# Which encoding can be used to mess up common English alphabet [a-zA-Z]?

Tags: string, unicode, encoding

I have a input string which consists of common English alphabet and space and its original encoding is `utf-8`

I want to find a encoding which can obfuscate this string. In other words, I want to purposefully apply this encoding to "mess up" my original input string. I have tried several in this list : [java supported encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html). But the original input string prints out unchanged.

Comment: What do you mean by 'mess up'? I'm assuming you want to either replace each letter with a random one, or swap letters around randomly.

Comment: @0liveradam8 "mess up" means un-readable. I want to keep the correct encoding only to myself. And other person won't see the original string unless he knows the correct encoding.

Comment: @0liveradam8 "replacing" a random letter is not preferred, I am trying to do this obfuscation only through manipulating charset encoding.

Comment: i think you may be looking for the [vernam cipher](https://www.cryptomuseum.com/crypto/vernam.htm). Given an input string, it encodes it using a randomised key. Only people who have the key would be able to read the original string. It is unbreakable.

Comment: @0liveradam8 ok thanks.